# How to Run C# application that uses MySQL on another PC?

Tags: c#, mysql

I know this subject was discussed here before, but it looks like there are several opinions.
My C# App is connected to a Database using MySQL, I created an installer for it and tried to run it on another PC.
The program didn't work.
How can I make it run on others PCs?
How to include the MySQL Database with my installation package?

If I used the localDatabase in visual Studio 2013 instead of MySQL will this solve my issue and make the application run on other PCs?

When I use the localDatabase; a (*.mdf) file is copied to the debug folder, if I just included this file in the installation package, will it be enough?

[image]

Comment: What does “didn't work” mean and how did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: @DourHighArch I mean that the application opened normal, but when I try to retrieve data I get the msg (No MySQL detected on this device)